# Unable to pass data from asp.net to javascript function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my asp.net code where I'm passing 4 values to the javascript function fnInsertLeave.

Below is the javascript function,unable to get values in the function

```js
"</td>" +
"<td><input type='submit' id='btnsubmitleave' onclick=fnInsertLeave(" + emp.ID + ",'" + emp.Name + "','fromdate" + index + "','todate" + index + "')/></td>" +
  "</tr>",
```

in the function I'm not getting values

```
function fnInsertLeave(id,name,fromdate,todate) {}
```

Comment: why you are mixing .net and html

Comment: Is your javascript function triggering on button click? The correct syntax is onclick=\"fnInsertLeave(" + emp.ID + ",'" + emp.Name + "','fromdate" + index + "','todate" + index + "')\"

Comment: *html codes in quotes*? are you constructing the html in Javascript? or Are you using RazorViews? or Are you constructing them in your Controller?

Answer (score 0):

always keep html ( display code ) and .net ( processing ) code separate
use form post method to submit this form to asp ( which will actually do all the processing task)